# problems with converting a string into a variable name and use it for plot in a loop in R

Tags: r, list, ggplot2

I want to make a series of plots with a for loop, then store all the plots in a list, and at last print all the plots to a .pdf file.
All my y variable names are stored in a char vector, and I need to loop through this vector to make a plot for each of them.

```
data <- data.frame(index = seq(1, 10, 1), var1 = (1:10)^2, var2 = (1:10)^3, var3 = (1:10) ^4)
varnames <- c("var1", "var2", "var3") # store all the names in a char vector. 
plot.list <- list() # make a list to store the result
for (i in varnames) {
  plot.list[[i]] = 
    ggplot(data, aes(x = index, y = as.name(i))) +
  geom_point() 
}
```

Here are my questions:

1. when I used y = as.name(i) to convert each element of varnames into a varible name, I got an error. The error is like this:

Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type name. Defaulting to continuous.
Error: Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): y = as.name(i).
Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add after_stat()?

Why did this happen and how to resolve it?

2. I want to store each plot into the plot.list, is this the right way to do it?

plot.list = some_plot_funtion()

3. How to plot all the elements in the plot.list to a .pdf
   Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to plot since it returns a list by default.

```
library(ggplot2)

plot.list <- lapply(varnames, function(x) 
                    ggplot(data, aes(index, .data[[x]])) + geom_point())


ggsave(filename = "plots.pdf", 
  plot = gridExtra::marrangeGrob(plot.list, nrow=1, ncol=1), 
  width = 15, height = 9)
```

You can adjust `width` and `height` as per your choice.

Comment: Thank you, Shan. what does .data[[x]] ? I cannot find help on it.

Comment: When you pass column name as string they need to be referred with `.data` in `aes`. You can refer - https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this very minor modification of your code. The `get` function acts in the manner both you and I think that `as.name` should work (but doesn't):

```
data <- data.frame(index = seq(1, 10, 1), var1 = (1:10)^2, var2 = (1:10)^3, var3 = (1:10) ^4)
varnames <- c("var1", "var2", "var3") # store all the names in a char vector. 
plot.list <- list() # make a list to store the result
for (i in varnames) {
    p = 
        ggplot(data, aes(x = index, y = get(i) )) +
        geom_point() ;  print(p); plot.list[[i]] <- p
}
```

You also need to do something to force evaluation of the print object. I tried using `force` but that failed. So I used `print` which does have the disadvantage of a side-effect of getting the individual plots to appear on your active graphics device.

Comment: Thank you, IRTFM. I tried get(i) before and had the same problem with you. Shah's answer works for me. Actually the .data[[i]] is the key to this answer. Look here https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html for more information about .data[[]] if you need.

Comment: That page introducing the dplyr-variant of the R language is a good illustration of why I have never thought it cost effective to learn it. I already knew the base R syntax easonably well, and then Hadley decided it was too complex but he decided to "simplify" it by making a ton of special cases. I don't think it came out any simpler.